# How to remove the space between rows in card (Flutter)

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

I used a card widget in my flutter App that has two rows, the problem that I have is a large space appeared between the two rows as you can see in the following image

[image]

how can fix this problem ?

my code that i tried it here :

```
return Card(

                      child: Container(
                        alignment: FractionalOffset.center,
                        child: Row(
                          children: <Widget>[
                            Expanded(
                              flex: 1,
                              child: Container(
                                child: ListTile(

                                  title: Text(snapshot.data[index].data["title"],
                                    textDirection: TextDirection.rtl,
                                    style: TextStyle(fontSize: 14.0,
                                        fontFamily: 'Cairo',
                                        fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),),
                                  onTap: () => navigateToDetails(snapshot.data[index]),

                                ),
                              ),
                            ),
                            //SizedBox(width: 1.0),
                            Expanded(
                              flex: 1,
                              child: Container(child: Image.network(snapshot.data[index].data["image_url"],height: 80.0,width: 80.0)),
                            ),


                          ],
                        ),
                      ),
                    );
```

Answer (score 0):

add `MainAxisAlignment`:`MainAxisAlignment.center`  property to your `Row` widget

followed code should work for you check this out.

```
  return Card(
    child: Container(
      alignment: FractionalOffset.center,
      child: Row(
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
        children: <Widget>[
          Expanded(
            flex: 1,
            child: Container(
              child: ListTile(
                title: Text(
                  snapshot.data[index].data["title"],
                  textDirection: TextDirection.rtl,
                  style: TextStyle(
                      fontSize: 14.0,
                      fontFamily: 'Cairo',
                      fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
                ),
                onTap: () => navigateToDetails(snapshot.data[index]),
              ),
            ),
          ),
          //SizedBox(width: 1.0),
          Expanded(
            flex: 1,
            child: Container(
                child: Image.network(snapshot.data[index].data["image_url"],
                    height: 80.0, width: 80.0)),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    ),
  );
```

Comment: it's still the same problem

Answer (score 0):

you are using expanded widget inside row so that both the widget try to get same width  and also try to cover whole width possible.

so that, if you want to remove space between row widget then remove expanded widget and play with **MainAxisAlignment** property of Row to arrange or manage the space.

you can use values like:

**MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween** and **MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly**

Comment: the problem that when i remove expanded widget and replace it with a Container widget the ListTile contents is disappear